# XamlParseException when trying to access Image from Resource directory

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing

Im using the following code to define a ImageBrush in a Window or UserControl:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="WindowBackground" Stretch="None" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/bg1.tif"/>
```

This works great, if I use it in my normal application.

But for my testing project when I'm trying to instantiate this, I always get a XamlParseException for this line.

Any hints how to avoid that?

```
   [TestMethod]
   public void TestMethod1()
   {
      MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the `/Resources/bg1.tif` file is copied into the directory into which your application builds and runs (eg `/bin/Debug`), but not into the directory your test project builds into. You will probably need to add a post build step to copy this directory across to your test project build output dir.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you know if this can be solved using DeploymentItem ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475(v=vs.80).aspx I would prefer that than copying the images

Comment: I don't use MSTest so can't say for sure, but certainly looks like a scenario DeploymentItem was designed for